# Place document.write string in element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using

```
document.write("Your IP is :", userip)
```

To output IP that I targets for a specific use - I need to hide this string in the dom. I tried this and It shows in a span in the dom but not fully working:

```
document.write("<span>\Your IP is :\, userip</span>");
```

If I tried to add a class to it it didn't work at all.

How Do I hide it, but keeping it in the DOM?

Comment: `document.write("<span>\Your IP is :\," + userip + "</span>");` is what you need because the userip would otherwise be a string.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you want to give the user some information while not showing the user that information; and what do you mean that it is "*not fully working*"?

Comment: Why do you have random `\\` characters?

Comment: `document.write("<span style='display:none;'>\Your IP is :\," + userip + "</span>");`

Answer (score 2):

You could do this as follows:

```
document.write('<span style="display:none">Your IP is :' + userip + '</span>');
```

But consider [not using `document.write`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/802943/5459839) at all, and using DOM methods to insert content once the document is loaded.